# How to test template context variables with Flask

Tags: python, flask

Django's test client returns a test Response object which includes the template context variables that were used to render the template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Response.context

How can I get access to template context variables while testing in Flask?

Example view:

```
@pgt.route('/myview')
def myview():
    context = {
        'var1': 'value 1',
        'var2': 'value 2',
        'var3': 'value 3',
    }
    return render_template('mytemplate.html', **context)
```

Example test:

```
class MyViewTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def test_get_success(self):
        response = self.client.get('/pgt/myview')

        # I don't want to do this
        self.assertIn('value 1', response.data)

        # I want to do something like this
        self.assertEqual(response.template_context['var1'], 'value 1')
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Thanks to [@andrewwatts](https://twitter.com/#!/andrewwatts) I used (a version of) [Flask-Testing](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Testing)

```
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase


class MyViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        # This method is required by flask.ext.testing.TestCase. It is called
        # before setUp().
        return create_app()

    def test_get_success(self):
        response = self.client.get('/pgt/myview')
        self.assertEqual(self.get_context_variable('var1'), 'value 1')
```

Answer (score -1):

From this limited information, I would suggest breaking the context-producing code into a separate unit and test that directly. Mapping the example above:

```
def get_context():
    context = {
        'var1': 'value 1',
        'var2': 'value 2',
        'var3': 'value 3',
    }
    return context

@pgt.route('/myview')
def myview():
    return render_template('mytemplate.html', **get_context())
```

Comment: The template context should be created inside of the view function/method. To place it outside only for testing is not a good way. The better way is to test the context via [flask-testing](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Testing/).